# How do I unlock the Songweaver class?

Tags: moon-hunters

The Songweaver class is locked at the start of Moon Hunters. How do I unlock it for future playthroughs?

Answer (score 3):

You have to find Soundweaver on the game, normally on the forest's stages, speak whit her, choose the option "Listen" and next finish the area. Once you go to the camp, speak again with here in front of the firecamp, and select the most pasive option and done! You can Play as Soundweaver in your future Travels :)